# How can I find unused functions in a PHP project

Tags: php

How can I find any unused functions in a PHP project?

Are there features or APIs built into PHP that will allow me to analyse my codebase - for example [Reflection](http://ie.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.reflection.php), [`token_get_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php)?

Are these APIs feature rich enough for me not to have to rely on a third party tool to perform this type of analysis?

Comment: Try out the [PHP Test Coverage Tool](http://www.semdesigns.com/products/testcoverage/PHPTestCoverage.html).

Comment: [Xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org/) can also provide [code coverage](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/code_coverage). You could use it in combination with the auto_prepend_file and auto_append_file [ini directives](http://php.net/ini.core) to log code coverage of your application during general use.

Comment: `xdebug` can tell you that with code coverage analysis http://www.xdebug.org/docs/code_coverage

Comment: I find that a simple file search can often do already - as long as you're not using variable function names and the like.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Thanks Greg and Dave for the feedback. Wasn't quite what I was looking for, but I decided to put a bit of time into researching it and came up with this quick and dirty solution:

```
<?php
    $functions = array();
    $path = "/path/to/my/php/project";
    define_dir($path, $functions);
    reference_dir($path, $functions);
    echo
        "<table>" .
            "<tr>" .
                "<th>Name</th>" .
                "<th>Defined</th>" .
                "<th>Referenced</th>" .
            "</tr>";
    foreach ($functions as $name => $value) {
        echo
            "<tr>" . 
                "<td>" . htmlentities($name) . "</td>" .
                "<td>" . (isset($value[0]) ? count($value[0]) : "-") . "</td>" .
                "<td>" . (isset($value[1]) ? count($value[1]) : "-") . "</td>" .
            "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    function define_dir($path, &$functions) {
        if ($dir = opendir($path)) {
            while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
                if (substr($file, 0, 1) == ".") continue;
                if (is_dir($path . "/" . $file)) {
                    define_dir($path . "/" . $file, $functions);
                } else {
                    if (substr($file, - 4, 4) != ".php") continue;
                    define_file($path . "/" . $file, $functions);
                }
            }
        }       
    }
    function define_file($path, &$functions) {
        $tokens = token_get_all(file_get_contents($path));
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($tokens); $i++) {
            $token = $tokens[$i];
            if (is_array($token)) {
                if ($token[0] != T_FUNCTION) continue;
                $i++;
                $token = $tokens[$i];
                if ($token[0] != T_WHITESPACE) die("T_WHITESPACE");
                $i++;
                $token = $tokens[$i];
                if ($token[0] != T_STRING) die("T_STRING");
                $functions[$token[1]][0][] = array($path, $token[2]);
            }
        }
    }
    function reference_dir($path, &$functions) {
        if ($dir = opendir($path)) {
            while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
                if (substr($file, 0, 1) == ".") continue;
                if (is_dir($path . "/" . $file)) {
                    reference_dir($path . "/" . $file, $functions);
                } else {
                    if (substr($file, - 4, 4) != ".php") continue;
                    reference_file($path . "/" . $file, $functions);
                }
            }
        }       
    }
    function reference_file($path, &$functions) {
        $tokens = token_get_all(file_get_contents($path));
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($tokens); $i++) {
            $token = $tokens[$i];
            if (is_array($token)) {
                if ($token[0] != T_STRING) continue;
                if ($tokens[$i + 1] != "(") continue;
                $functions[$token[1]][1][] = array($path, $token[2]);
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

I'll probably spend some more time on it so I can quickly find the files and line numbers of the function definitions and references; this information is being gathered, just not displayed.

Comment: This solution is good if you never use `call_user_func()` or `call_user_func_array()` or `$var()`

Comment: I had to replace the two `die()` with `continue` for this to not choke on anonymous functions.

Answer (score 36):

You can try Sebastian Bergmann's Dead Code Detector:

**Note:** *Dead Code Detector has been archived by the owner on Nov 9, 2017*

**Alternative tools**:

- https://phpqa.io/
- https://github.com/phpmd/phpmd

**Dead Code Detector:**

> `phpdcd` is a Dead Code Detector (DCD) for PHP code. It scans a PHP project for all declared functions and methods and reports those as being "dead code" that are not called at least once.

Source: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpdcd

Note that it's a static code analyzer, so it might give false positives for methods that only called dynamically, e.g. it cannot detect `$foo = 'fn'; $foo();`

You can install it via PEAR:

```
pear install phpunit/phpdcd-beta
```

After that you can use with the following options:

```
Usage: phpdcd [switches] <directory|file> ...

--recursive Report code as dead if it is only called by dead code.

--exclude <dir> Exclude <dir> from code analysis.
--suffixes <suffix> A comma-separated list of file suffixes to check.

--help Prints this usage information.
--version Prints the version and exits.

--verbose Print progress bar.
```

---

**Note:** as per the repository notice, *this project is no longer maintained and its repository is only kept for archival purposes*. So your mileage may vary.

Comment: From the github page: "This project is no longer maintained and its repository is only kept for archival purposes."

Comment: @BurhanAli no longer maintained doesnt necessarily mean that its no longer working. Feel free to take over maintenance.

Comment: @Gordon There is a reason it's not maintained anymore, the large spectrum of method calls  it doesn't detects: "Class::method()" and constructors are reported as not used for example. The reflection approach is not the ideal for a dynamic language, and so improve the tool would in reality mean rewrite a new one using another approach to detect the methods used.

Comment: @Dereckson yes, I agree. but until someone finally does that, this *is* still better than nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the "more tools" links, that also refer to the "PHP Mess Detector" (http://phpmd.org/)

Answer (score 22):

This bit of bash scripting might help:

```
grep -rhio ^function\ .*\(  .|awk -F'[( ]'  '{print "echo -n " $2 " && grep -rin " $2 " .|grep -v function|wc -l"}'|bash|grep 0
```

This basically recursively greps the current directory for function definitions, passes the hits to awk, which forms a command to do the following:

- print the function name
- recursively grep for it again
- piping that output to grep -v to filter out function definitions so as to retain calls to the function
- pipes this output to wc -l which prints the line count

This command is then sent for execution to bash and the output is grepped for 0, which would indicate 0 calls to the function.

Note that this will *not* solve the problem calebbrown cites above, so there might be some false positives in the output.

Comment: Love it!  Quick and dirty and practical.  Here's a version updated for modern PHP.  Remove the `sort -u` (remove duplicates) optimization if you prefer the functions in file order rather than alpha.
`egrep -rhio 'function\ \w+\('  .|sort -u |awk -F'[( ]'  '{print "echo -n " $2 " && grep -rin " $2 " .|grep -v function |wc -l"}'| bash | grep ' 0$'`

Answer (score 10):

USAGE: **find_unused_functions.php <root_directory>**

NOTE: This is a ‘quick-n-dirty’ approach to the problem. This script only performs a lexical pass over the files, and does not respect situations where different modules define identically named functions or methods. If you use an IDE for your PHP development, it may offer a more comprehensive solution.

Requires PHP 5

To save you a copy and paste, a direct download, and any new versions, are **[available here](https://github.com/andreybutov/find-unused-php-functions)**.

```
#!/usr/bin/php -f
 
<?php
 
// ============================================================================
//
// find_unused_functions.php
//
// Find unused functions in a set of PHP files.
// version 1.3
//
// ============================================================================
//
// Copyright (c) 2011, Andrey Butov. All Rights Reserved.
// This script is provided as is, without warranty of any kind.
//
// http://www.andreybutov.com
//
// ============================================================================
 
// This may take a bit of memory...
ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');
 
if ( !isset($argv[1]) ) 
{
    usage();
}
 
$root_dir = $argv[1];
 
if ( !is_dir($root_dir) || !is_readable($root_dir) )
{
    echo "ERROR: '$root_dir' is not a readable directory.\n";
    usage();
}
 
$files = php_files($root_dir);
$tokenized = array();
 
if ( count($files) == 0 )
{
    echo "No PHP files found.\n";
    exit;
}
 
$defined_functions = array();
 
foreach ( $files as $file )
{
    $tokens = tokenize($file);
 
    if ( $tokens )
    {
        // We retain the tokenized versions of each file,
        // because we'll be using the tokens later to search
        // for function 'uses', and we don't want to 
        // re-tokenize the same files again.
 
        $tokenized[$file] = $tokens;
 
        for ( $i = 0 ; $i < count($tokens) ; ++$i )
        {
            $current_token = $tokens[$i];
            $next_token = safe_arr($tokens, $i + 2, false);
 
            if ( is_array($current_token) && $next_token && is_array($next_token) )
            {
                if ( safe_arr($current_token, 0) == T_FUNCTION )
                {
                    // Find the 'function' token, then try to grab the 
                    // token that is the name of the function being defined.
                    // 
                    // For every defined function, retain the file and line
                    // location where that function is defined. Since different
                    // modules can define a functions with the same name,
                    // we retain multiple definition locations for each function name.
 
                    $function_name = safe_arr($next_token, 1, false);
                    $line = safe_arr($next_token, 2, false);
 
                    if ( $function_name && $line )
                    {
                        $function_name = trim($function_name);
                        if ( $function_name != "" )
                        {
                            $defined_functions[$function_name][] = array('file' => $file, 'line' => $line);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
 
// We now have a collection of defined functions and
// their definition locations. Go through the tokens again, 
// and find 'uses' of the function names. 
 
foreach ( $tokenized as $file => $tokens )
{
    foreach ( $tokens as $token )
    {
        if ( is_array($token) && safe_arr($token, 0) == T_STRING )
        {
            $function_name = safe_arr($token, 1, false);
            $function_line = safe_arr($token, 2, false);;
 
            if ( $function_name && $function_line )
            {
                $locations_of_defined_function = safe_arr($defined_functions, $function_name, false);
 
                if ( $locations_of_defined_function )
                {
                    $found_function_definition = false;
 
                    foreach ( $locations_of_defined_function as $location_of_defined_function )
                    {
                        $function_defined_in_file = $location_of_defined_function['file'];
                        $function_defined_on_line = $location_of_defined_function['line'];
 
                        if ( $function_defined_in_file == $file && 
                             $function_defined_on_line == $function_line )
                        {
                            $found_function_definition = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
 
                    if ( !$found_function_definition )
                    {
                        // We found usage of the function name in a context
                        // that is not the definition of that function. 
                        // Consider the function as 'used'.
 
                        unset($defined_functions[$function_name]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
 
 
print_report($defined_functions);   
exit;
 
 
// ============================================================================
 
function php_files($path) 
{
    // Get a listing of all the .php files contained within the $path
    // directory and its subdirectories.
 
    $matches = array();
    $folders = array(rtrim($path, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR));
 
    while( $folder = array_shift($folders) ) 
    {
        $matches = array_merge($matches, glob($folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."*.php", 0));
        $moreFolders = glob($folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
        $folders = array_merge($folders, $moreFolders);
    }
 
    return $matches;
}
 
// ============================================================================
 
function safe_arr($arr, $i, $default = "")
{
    return isset($arr[$i]) ? $arr[$i] : $default;
}
 
// ============================================================================
 
function tokenize($file)
{
    $file_contents = file_get_contents($file);
 
    if ( !$file_contents )
    {
        return false;
    }
 
    $tokens = token_get_all($file_contents);
    return ($tokens && count($tokens) > 0) ? $tokens : false;
}
 
// ============================================================================
 
function usage()
{
    global $argv;
    $file = (isset($argv[0])) ? basename($argv[0]) : "find_unused_functions.php";
    die("USAGE: $file <root_directory>\n\n");
}
 
// ============================================================================
 
function print_report($unused_functions)
{
    if ( count($unused_functions) == 0 )
    {
        echo "No unused functions found.\n";
    }
 
    $count = 0;
    foreach ( $unused_functions as $function => $locations )
    {
        foreach ( $locations as $location )
        {
            echo "'$function' in {$location['file']} on line {$location['line']}\n";
            $count++;
        }
    }
 
    echo "=======================================\n";
    echo "Found $count unused function" . (($count == 1) ? '' : 's') . ".\n\n";
}
 
// ============================================================================
 
/* EOF */
```

Comment: Just awesome, thanks Andrey! I'm turning this into coding standard checker with lot of your help: https://github.com/Symplify/Symplify/pull/466

Comment: Thanks Andrey! You might want to update the link though!

Answer (score 8):

## 2020 Update

I have used the other methods outlined above, even the **2019 update answer here is outdated**.

Tomáš Votruba's answer led me to find Phan as the ECS route has now been deprecated. Symplify have removed the dead public method checker.

### Phan is a static analyzer for PHP

We can utilise Phan to search for dead code. Here are the steps to take using composer to install. These steps are also found on the [git repo for phan](https://github.com/phan/phan). These instructions assume you're at the root of your project.

### Step 1 - Install Phan w/ composer

```
composer require phan/phan
```

### Step 2 - Install php-ast

`PHP-AST` is a requirement for Phan
As I'm using WSL, I've been able to use PECL to install, however, other install methods for `php-ast` can be found in a git repo

```
pecl install ast
```

### Step 3 - Locate and edit php.ini to use php-ast

Locate current `php.ini`

```
php -i | grep 'php.ini'
```

Now take that file location and nano (or whichever of your choice to edit this doc). Locate the area of all extensions and ADD the following line:

```
extension=ast.so
```

### Step 4 - create a config file for Phan

Steps on config file can be found in Phan's documentation on [how to create a config file](https://github.com/phan/phan/wiki/Getting-Started#creating-a-config-file)
You'll want to use their sample one as it's a good starting point. Edit the following arrays to add your own paths on both
`directory_list` & `exclude_analysis_directory_list`.
Please note that `exclude_analysis_directory_list` will still be parsed but not validated eg. adding Wordpress directory here would mean, false positives for called wordpress functions in your theme would not appear as it found the function in wordpress but at the same time it'll not validate functions in wordpress' folder.
Mine looked like this

```
......

'directory_list' => [
  'public_html'
],

......

'exclude_analysis_directory_list' => [
    'vendor/',
    'public_html/app/plugins',
    'public_html/app/mu-plugins',
    'public_html/admin'
],
......
```

### Step 5 - Run Phan with dead code detection

Now that we've installed phan and ast, configured the folders we wish to parse, it's time to run Phan. We'll be passing an argument to phan `--dead-code-detection` which is self explanatory.

```
./vendor/bin/phan --dead-code-detection
```

This output will need verifying with a fine tooth comb but it's certainly the best place to start

The output will look like this in console

```
the/path/to/php/file.php:324 PhanUnreferencedPublicMethod Possibly zero references to public method\the\path\to\function::the_funciton()
the/path/to/php/file.php:324 PhanUnreferencedPublicMethod Possibly zero references to public method\the\path\to\function::the_funciton()
the/path/to/php/file.php:324 PhanUnreferencedPublicMethod Possibly zero references to public method\the\path\to\function::the_funciton()
the/path/to/php/file.php:324 PhanUnreferencedPublicMethod Possibly zero references to public method\the\path\to\function::the_funciton()
```

Please feel free to add to this answer or correct my mistakes :)

Answer (score 3):

If I remember correctly you can use [phpCallGraph](http://phpcallgraph.sourceforge.net/) to do that. It'll generate a nice graph (image) for you with all the methods involved. If a method is not connected to any other, that's a good sign that the method is orphaned.

Here's an example: [classGallerySystem.png](http://phpcallgraph.sourceforge.net/examples/refactoring-candidates/class_GallerySystem.png)

The method `getKeywordSetOfCategories()` is orphaned.

Just by the way, you don't have to take an image -- phpCallGraph can also *generate* a text file, or a PHP array, etc..

Answer (score 3):

Because PHP functions/methods can be dynamically invoked, there is no programmatic way to know with certainty if a function will never be called.

The only certain way is through manual analysis.

Answer (score 3):

### 2019+ Update

I got inspied by [Andrey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532/how-can-i-find-unused-functions-in-a-php-project/7133253#7133253) and turned this into a coding standard sniff.

The detection is very simple yet powerful:

- finds all methods `public function someMethod()`
- then find all method calls `${anything}->someMethod()`
- and simply **reports those public functions that were never called**

It helped me to remove [over](https://github.com/Symplify/Symplify/commit/fa21855694d933716117b2a2db13acac55b86d69) [20+ methods](https://github.com/Symplify/Symplify/commit/3f08ed1fb2f22dd6c4a7b46d680adf4ab5a0907d) I would have to maintain and test.

### 3 Steps to Find them

Install ECS:

```
composer require symplify/easy-coding-standard --dev
```

Set up `ecs.yaml` config:

```
# ecs.yaml
services:
    Symplify\CodingStandard\Sniffs\DeadCode\UnusedPublicMethodSniff: ~
```

Run the command:

```
vendor/bin/ecs check src
```

See reported methods and remove those you don't fine useful

---

You can read more about it here: [Remove Dead Public Methods from Your Code](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2019/03/14/remove-dead-public-methdos-from-your-code/)

Comment: **It works.** Validated its output with a simple search for the mentioned unused functions. Some remarks: You should add your `tests` folder to the command like `vendor/bin/ecs check src tests`. Without it, you may get more false positives. Thank you Tomáš Votruba for this.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'm glad it works well for you!
As for tests, if you include them, you might get false positives, because the public methods **would be called only in the tests**. This is actually fixed in newer version of the sniff.

Comment: Symplify have now removed UnusedPublicMethodSniff from CodeStandard. Reference https://github.com/symplify/symplify/pull/1862. There is another method that works (as at Oct 2020) with Phan. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

[phpxref](http://phpxref.sourceforge.net/) will identify where functions are called from which would facilitate the analysis - but there's still a certain amount of manual effort involved.

Answer (score -1):

afaik there is no way. To know which functions "are belonging to whom" you would need to execute the system (runtime late binding function lookup).

But Refactoring tools are based on static code analysis. I really like dynamic typed languages, but in my view they are difficult to scale. The lack of safe refactorings in large codebases and dynamic typed languages is a major drawback for maintainability and handling software evolution.