# Find out never-called functions in Python?

Tags: python, function, pyramid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can you find unused functions in Python code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693070/how-can-you-find-unused-functions-in-python-code)

I'm working on a Pyramid project many files and functions, and in an effort to clean things up I would like to know which functions are never called. Is there a way to figure this out?

Thanks

Comment: Thankx, I'll try pylint to see how it works

Comment: And, specific to the Pyramid project; pyramid uses unit tests together with `coverage` to ensure that the codebase is fully tested and that everything in the codebase has a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use static analysers, such as [pychecker](http://pychecker.sourceforge.net/).