# How to find all unused methods of a class in PyCharm?

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm

I have a class named `Article` in my project. I want to find all its methods that are unused in the project. For a particular method I can press `Alt+F7` and see where it's used, and if it's not used anywhere, I can delete it safely. Is it possible to automate the process and find all methods of the class that are unused without pressing `Alt+F7` for each method?

Answer (score 46):

PyCharm doesn't offer this feature since it isn't possible to reliably determine that a method is unused, because [there are simply too many ways to call it dynamically.](http://forum.jetbrains.com/thread/PyCharm-1212)

But you may use [Vulture](https://github.com/jendrikseipp/vulture) to find most of dead code in a project. Refer to the following commands:

```
$ pip install -U vulture
$ vulture path_of_project
$ # Use --exclude for excluding particular files (e.g. virtualenv files)
$ vulture --exclude=env path_of_project
```

Comment: Awesome package name. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693070/how-can-you-find-unused-functions-in-python-code

Comment: I just tried this out on a version 2.7 codebase, and it's not picking up completely unreferenced class methods, but giving them a 60% confidence; so Vulture does not get a very high score in my situation. Your mileage may vary. It's still a good pointer, but for me, Vulture merely gives hints.