# Did pycharm has hint that make method become grey when not being called?

Tags: pycharm

When I used android studio, this hint is amazing that can let me know the unused method in my program. But when I use pycharm, this hint is gone? Do anyone know that this hint function is still in pycharm or not? can I turn this function on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No.**

Similar question: [How to find all unused methods of a class in PyCharm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26839721/how-to-find-all-unused-methods-of-a-class-in-pycharm)

See [JetBrains staff answer about unused methods in PyCharm](http://forum.jetbrains.com/thread/PyCharm-1212)