# How do I find and remove unused functions in Python code files?

Tags: python

I have a Python code file with many functions in it.  I'm only using a few.  Is there a tool available to remove all of the unused ones for me?

Comment: By running WHAT Python program?

Comment: What do you mean by "remove the functions"? Do you mean actually directly edit the source files to remove them?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for something like this:  https://github.com/jendrikseipp/vulture\

Comment: yes...and only in these custom python files.

Comment: You keep saying things like "this" and "these", but I see no code or references to code.

Comment: It is just a python program with many functions, but I only need one or two function in it...

Comment: Steve, I think the link you post here is actually what I need...Thank you very much~

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you find unused functions in Python code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693070/how-can-you-find-unused-functions-in-python-code)

Answer (score 4):

As Steve mentioned in the comments, you could use *Vulture*.

Here's an [example from the documentation](https://github.com/jendrikseipp/vulture#examples)

> Consider the following Python script (dead_code.py):
>
> ```
> import os
>
> class Greeter:
>     def greet(self):
>         print("Hi")
>
> def hello_world():
>     message = "Hello, world!"
>     greeter = Greeter()
>     greet_func = getattr(greeter, "greet")
>     greet_func()
>
> if __name__ == "__main__":
>     hello_world()
> ```
>
> Calling
>
> ```
> vulture dead_code.py
> ```
>
> results in the following output:
>
> ```
> dead_code.py:1: unused import 'os' (90% confidence)
> dead_code.py:4: unused function 'greet' (60% confidence)
> dead_code.py:8: unused variable 'message' (60% confidence)
> ```

Comment: After reading this post i installed vulture and the hardest thing to do was to add it to my tools list in pyscripter. Works like a charm