# Any tool to find out what functions are not used in a PHP Application?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I find unused functions in a PHP project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532/how-can-i-find-unused-functions-in-a-php-project)

I find that sometimes, after developing for sometime, some functions that are not used are still in the code. Its hard to track these, some IDE's will highlight unused variables, but functions?

It will be something like Code Coverage but not for unit tests