# Why do I get a fatal error "redeclaring" a function that's only declared once?

Tags: php, mysql

(Coding PHP with MySQL)

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare logged_in() (previously declared in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\Func\user.func.php:9) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\Func\user.func.php on line 9

I'm making a function to check if a user is logged in. I declare the function as `logged_in() {}`, but the function causes the error seen above, even though I've never declared it before.

The function didn't work when it was defined either, with an isset and a reference to MySQL code.

Comment: May you show the complete line declaring the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> even though I've never declared it before?

It must have been declared previously somewhere.

Maybe you are including `user.func.php` twice?

Comment: +1 Here's a hint to prevent such errors: prefer `include_once` over `include`!

Answer (score 0):

If you can't work out whether you've declared it before, use [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532/tool-to-find-unused-functions-in-php-project/14625#14625) in a separate test class.  It'll identify how many times you've called the function.

If it says it's being called before, download a search program like [grepWin](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/grepWin.html&rct=j&q=grepwin&ei=-YlPTrmBMtGChQfq4YTABg&usg=AFQjCNHBkNIASZLrESEMbTgXKYIvKdLXnA&sig2=pMXMsYghEB0ZUu5NVeLZ4g&cad=rja) and search your public_html folder for the file that's hosting your rogue function.