# What's the best way to identify which php scripts aren't used anymore?

Tags: php

When inheriting the maintenance programming of a large web application that has many php5 scripts (4000+), what is the best way to determine which scripts are no longer in use and can probably be removed?

Comment: What's in my mind would be a script that goes trough the directory collect all script names and the open's every script and search if a script is anywhere included or used! (Don't think it's the best solution but it could work)

Comment: Maybe there is some sort of mechanism in php5 (or a module) to log all include/requires?

Comment: you could create a new folder, paste in the master index.php and then copy in that file one by one all the scripts that php will be whining about... a monk's work, to be certain

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I find unused functions in a PHP project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532/how-can-i-find-unused-functions-in-a-php-project)

Comment: Finding unused functions is one part of the problem... these scripts are using conditional includes etc. Another idea I had was to gather script accesses via apache2 access logs over a week or so.

Comment: Created php5 extension here https://github.com/campbeld1 that logs file names to syslog. Will accumulate a lot, however, another process could remove duplicates from the log. Then the set of scripts in the source base could be compared to the set in the de-duplicated logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a project [Dead Code Detector (DCD)](http://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpdcd).

It finds functions that are never called, which may help to clean up even the files you keep in production.

For finding out unused files, no firm software/algorithm exists for PHP (at least as per my knowledge).

For finding unused files, I think we should do it manually.

Comment: I'll accept this as the answer although "manually with some automated guidance" might be a better answer. It doesn't seem to be the best approach to work with a large code-base by opening up and inspecting every single file. There are often patterns in the code-base that can be exploited by automation.